# Is .gz the same as .gzip?

Tags: compression, gzip

I'm decompressing a file with a .gzip extension and then re-compressing it using 7Zip. When re-compressed though it has a .gz extension.

Are a .gz and .gzip extension the same thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are, but `.gz` is by far the more conventional extension to use.

Comment: How it is more "convenient"?

Comment: @RichardRiley I said "conventional", not "convenient", but it is 2 chars more convenient as well.

Comment: I had my blinkers on! Apologies.